# Keep the window's name fixed in tmux

Tags: linux, tmux

I want to keep the windows' name fixed after I rename it. But after I renaming it, they keep changing when I execute commands.

How can I keep them in a static name?

Comment: My massive tmux and zsh configs do something like this: https://github.com/richo/dotfiles/blob/master/tmux.conf https://github.com/richo/dotfiles/blob/master/zshrc Tmux disables auto updating, zshrc has a bunch of hacks to take a look at what I'm doing and update the title appropriately.

Comment: Seems like here's the solution: http://superuser.com/questions/306028/tmux-and-zsh-custom-prompt-bug-with-window-name

Comment: set-window-option -g automatic-rename off

Comment: ```set-option -g allow-rename off```

Comment: This question should be reopened.

Comment: @IanVaughan Why? To get it closed under a different reason?

Comment: @rene Nope, to remain open with an answer. Its a valid question, I had it, the OP had it, therefore others can/will have it. I found a solution to it, thus its a valid question with an answer.

Comment: @IanVaughan I doubt people will vote to reopen Can you add the command that set's window name so that non tmux users get the idea that this is not a give me the code question?

Comment: For just renaming the active window, `set-window-option -g allow-rename off` does the trick. I accidentally upvoted @Deshawn-willams 's answer there, but that did nothing.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed either. It's a direct question about a tool that's mostly used by Software Developers.

Comment: This was the top result when I searched for this problem in Google. This should be reopened. It's a valid question.

Comment: At least 72 people have found @Abhaya 's solution useful, let's get the answer actually recorded

Comment: @yasith: The site standards for topicality are ["problems involving... software tools commonly used by programmers ... and unique to software development"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  There's nothing here unique to software development, a network administrator using tmux to manage a bunch of remote shells would do it in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 176):

As shown in a comment to the main post: `set-option -g allow-rename off` in your `.tmux.conf` file

Comment: allow rename allows me to rename?? I want to be able to manually rename, but I dont want the window name to change after my manual rename is done

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed. It let the window be renamed automatically when launching a process, *but* prevent renaming once you have manually changed it. And you can re-rename it after.

Comment: @ArnoldRoa Interestingly `allow rename off` in `.tmux.conf` does the trick indeed, and it is not the other option `automatic-rename off`, which I would expect.

Comment: This worked for me!  This should be the accepted answer

Comment: For people using **byobu**, you should actually change `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Neither does `set-window-option -g allow-rename off` nor `allow rename off` from the comments above.

Comment: If some who could not find file `.tmux.conf`. Create `~/.tmux.conf` if not exists (by using `touch ~/.tmux.conf`). or just use `vim ~/.tmux.conf` and save.

Comment: @ostrokach, thank you for the note! But still don't forget to press F5 to reload the configs ;) Took me some minutes to figure it out

Comment: This also works within a tmux session. Typing your prefix key followed by a colon will allow you to type the command `set-option -g allow-rename off`.

Comment: I'm thinking that the `automatic-rename` option maybe controls tmux renaming the window that it's in?  like if it's a GUI terminal / xterm, etc, setting the name for its parent ... and then `allow-rename` controls whether the _child_ "windows" in tmux get renamed by their processes. I _think_. Not much clarity about it in the man page and wiki ... https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1

Answer (score 19):

### There are two ways to disable automatic rename.

#### 01. change `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file and add this line

```
export DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true
```

#### 02. or you can add this line to `~/.tmux.conf` file

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

- create it if it does not yet exist

---

- Highly recommend the second option
- Also you must reload the tmux config after changing the config.

This can be done either from within the tmux, by pressing `Ctrl+B` and then `:` to bring up a command prompt, and typing:

```
:source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Or simply from a shell:

```
$ tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: The `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf` command is indeed crucial. This answer is the most complete one!

Answer (score 15):

As suggested on the [Super User link](https://superuser.com/questions/306028/tmux-and-zsh-custom-prompt-bug-with-window-name/320316#320316), setting the following variable in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` seems to solve the issue:

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true
```

Answer (score 8):

```
# set-window-option -g automatic-rename off 
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

Comment the first one, and set the second one, in the ~/.tmux.conf It works for me.

Answer (score -6):

In my .zshrc file , add the following config, it solved this problem.

```
DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true
```

Comment: this answer added nothing to Jean Carlo's one.