# Tmux window title keeps renaming

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, tmux

Suddenly, both my screen/tmux started changing my windows' names after every command. They keep changing the name to the value of `$PROMPT_COMMAND` on every single action on the terminal, even after manually renaming them (by <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> on screen or <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> on tmux).

On tmux I already tried to change the `tmux.conf` settings to disable window auto renaming off, but seems that it was ignored.

I am using bash without the standard `/etc/bashrc` configuration file. My distro is Fedora 18.

Comment: Possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041178/keep-the-windows-name-fixed-in-tmux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether your `PS1` (plus `PS2`, `PS3` or `PS4` if those are set) is [changing the title](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/9a3d2ea4762194b3c6956651b20fd3fa696ee257/.bashrc#L116-L123):

```
printf %q "$PS1" | grep -F '\\033'
```

Answer (score 51):

Add the following to your tmux config file:

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

Answer (score 35):

Put this at the end of the `.tmux.conf` file:

```
set-window-option -g automatic-rename off
set-option -g allow-rename off
```

then reload the tmux config file (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> > <kbd>:</kbd> > `source-file ~/.tmux.conf`).

Comment: Isn't the second line enough? What is the first line for?

Comment: First line: https://that.guru/blog/automatically-set-tmux-window-name/
Second line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041178/keep-the-windows-name-fixed-in-tmux

Comment: For reference, to reload the file "Ctrl-b : source-file ~/.tmux.conf"

Answer (score 5):

First, if l0b0's answer fixed your problem could you please mark it as a solution? Second, for those of use who stumble upon this question and are using fedora 19 this [redhat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=969429#c5) may be of interest. It seems like the default value of $PROMPT_COMMAND set by /etc/bashrc has been changed recently. I reverted to the previous behavior like this:

```
echo 'printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\033\\" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"' > /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
chmod a+rx /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-screen
```