# Create new window and set name

Tags: tmux

Currently I'll often do <kbd>prefix-c</kbd><kbd>prefix-,</kbd> to open a new window then rename it. I would like to make  <kbd>prefix-c</kbd> automatically ask for a name for the new window.

Basically I want it to behave as if I'd entered  <kbd>prefix-:</kbd>`new-window -n`.How do I map  <kbd>prefix-c</kbd> to that command?

I've tried adding `bind-key c 'new-window -n'` to my ~/.tmux.conf but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll need a prompt to ask for the new window name:

```
bind-key c command-prompt -p "window name:" "new-window; rename-window '%%'"
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I do a `C-b c` and get prompted for the name, but then the name doesn't get used. I get some default name.

Comment: Nevermind. I needed to [stop automatic window renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289439/tmux-window-title-keeps-renaming). This solution works for me.