# Prevent tmux from displaying/replacing user-namespace from window's name

Tags: tmux

I would like to give fix name different tmux pane title but whenever I move to a different directory tmux just replace pane name that I have define with something like: `0:username@namespace:~/directory` which confusing. Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep the window's name fixed in tmux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041178/keep-the-windows-name-fixed-in-tmux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041178/keep-the-windows-name-fixed-in-tmux)
The tmux command for this is:

```
set-option -g allow-rename off
```