# How do I rename a pane in tmux?

Tags: tmux

How do I rename a pane in `tmux`?

Answer (score 376):

#### Renaming a window

`Ctrl-b` `,`

where `Ctrl-b` is the default prefix key.

Alternatively, run:

```
tmux rename-window <new name>
```

Or type `Ctrl-b` `:` `rename-window <new name>`.

---

#### Renaming a pane

In newer versions you can rename pane using:

```
tmux select-pane -T <title>
```

Or type `Ctrl-b` `:` `select-pane -T <pane_name>`.

Also, I have the following two lines in `~/.tmux.conf`, in order to view the title of the pane in the top of the pane itself, and reformat the title.

`set -g pane-border-status top`

`set -g pane-border-format " [ ###P #T ] "`

Comment: When I am renaming current window, I can not see what I am typing, is that by default? Or is it due to my configuration? Although I think my configuration is not preventing `tmux` from showing that.

Comment: To clarify, you _can_ rename a pane, and this is needed when accidentally binary output corrupts it.  @Mapad's answer resolves this.

Comment: that gets reverted back whenever you `ls`

Comment: @anilbey Same here. The solution to that is [`set-option -g allow-rename off`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34004541/99777)

Comment: This is useful, but it renames a window, not a pane.

Comment: it works on bash, but not on zsh for some reason. Any idea?

Comment: @A1m have you tried DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE=true in .zshrc?

Answer (score 60):

yes you can rename pane names, and not only window names starting with tmux >= 2.3. Just type the following in your shell:

```
printf '\033]2;%s\033\\' 'title goes here'
```

you might need to add the following to your .tmux.conf to display pane names:

```
# Enable names for panes
set -g pane-border-status top
```

you can also automatically assign a name:

```
set -g pane-border-format "#P: #{pane_current_command}"
```

Comment: Is there a way to put args of a command into pane border format?

Oh, there is a corresponding [issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/733) on github.

Comment: title length is 21

Comment: I tried your answer and it works for a brief second but then automatically renames to my home directory. I tried adding `setw -g automatic-rename off` but no luck.

Answer (score 26):

For those scripting tmux, there is a command called `rename-window`
so e.g.

```
tmux rename-window -t <window> <newname>
```

Comment: In my case was something like: `tmux rename-window -t 9 my-project`.

Comment: This is for windows, not panes, yah?

Comment: No it's for linux

Answer (score 14):

For those who want to easily rename their panes in a bash shell, this is what I have in my `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g default-command '                      \
function renamePane () {                      \
  read -p "Enter Pane Name: " pane_name;      \
  printf "\033]2;%s\033\\r:r" "${pane_name}"; \
};                                            \
export -f renamePane;                         \
bash -i'
set -g pane-border-status top
set -g pane-border-format "#{pane_index} #T #{pane_current_command}"
bind-key -T prefix R send-keys "renamePane" C-m
```

Panes are automatically named with their index, machine name and current command.
To change the machine name you can run `<C-b>R` which will prompt you to enter a new name.

**Pane renaming only works when you are in a shell.*

Comment: Be very careful with this. This screwed my tmux when I (?) id this incorrectly. Even though I could not find the renamePane function in any dotfiles, it persisted an error when starting tmux: "zsh:export:1: invalid option(s)". A reboot fixed this.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tested this on zsh, only bash shells.

Answer (score 6):

You can adjust the pane title by setting the pane border in the tmux.conf for example like this:

```
###############
# pane border #
###############
set -g pane-border-status bottom
#colors for pane borders
setw -g pane-border-style fg=green,bg=black
setw -g pane-active-border-style fg=colour118,bg=black
setw -g automatic-rename off
setw -g pane-border-format ' #{pane_index} #{pane_title} : #{pane_current_path} '
# active pane normal, other shaded out​
setw -g window-style fg=colour28,bg=colour16
setw -g window-active-style fg=colour46,bg=colour16
```

Where pane_index, pane_title and pane_current_path are variables provided by tmux itself.

After reloading the config or starting a new tmux session, you can then set the title of the current pane like this:

```
tmux select-pane -T "fancy pane title";
#or
tmux select-pane -t paneIndexInteger -T "fancy pane title";
```

If all panes have some processes running, so you can't use the command line, you can also type the commands after pressing the prefix bind (C-b by default) and a colon (:) without having "tmux" in the front of the command:

```
select-pane -T "fancy pane title"
#or:
select-pane -t paneIndexInteger -T "fancy pane title"
```

Comment: This mostly works for me, and the rename works and the placement is good. But then when I run another command, it still auto-renames the pane to something else. I am running fish inside, maybe there is something up with that.

Comment: I did kill the entire `tmux` process just to make sure config reloaded too. reloading it wasn't enough, as I was still seeing pane titles after I commented it out and reloaded.

Comment: @ElijahLynn
I have this custom keybinding defined in my tmux.conf for renaming pane titles on pressing Alt+P and it works just fine regardless of any running process in the shell:
`bind-key -n M-p command-prompt "set -p @custom_pane_title '%%'"`.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I added your binding and when I press `alt + p` I get a `(set)` in the bottom bar that accepts text input and when I press return it disappears and nothing happens. I'll keep tinkering with it. It must be something in my config, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Also when scripting, you can specify a name when creating the window with `-n <window name>`. For example:

```
# variable to store the session name
SESSION="my_session"

# set up session
tmux -2 new-session -d -s $SESSION

# create window; split into panes
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:0 -n 'My Window with a Name'
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest option for me was to rename the title of the terminal instead.
Please see: https://superuser.com/questions/362227/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-mintty-window

In this answer, they mention to modify the PS1 variable. Note: my situation was particular to cygwin.

TL;DR
Put this in your .bashrc file:

```
function settitle() {
      export PS1="\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n$ "
      echo -ne "\e]0;$1\a"
}
```

Put this in your .tmux.conf file, or similar formatting:

```
set -g pane-border-status bottom
set -g pane-border-format "#P #T #{pane_current_command}"
```

Then you can change the title of the pane by typing this in the console:

```
settitle titlename
```

Answer (score 2):

To rename the pane, write the following in the tmux command prompt:

```
select-pane -T 'NEW PANE NAME'
```

To bind it to a key (example: u) write the following in your `~/.tmux.conf` file:

```
bind u command-prompt "select-pane -T '%%'"
```

Then you can rename the pane just by `<prefix>u`

FYI:

- To open the command prompt you need to `<prefix>:`
- `<prefix>` is `C-b` by default (it can be changed with a `set -g prefix NEW_KEY`)

Answer (score 2):

I use `byobu` with `tmux` as backend and would like to provide an alternative way: If you have *Mouse-Mode* on (for me `Alt+F12`), you can just right click onto the pane and select *Rename*. It appears that you can only rename the currently selected pane.

[image]